estoy tratando de enviar un formulario con tres campos de los cuales uno es de tipo file, pero en el backend req.file es undefined

Cita en bloque  mi frontend que, funciona bien ya que en la consola de desarrollador aparecen los datos que carga el formulario. es el siguiente:
Cita en bloque

import React from 'react';
import {useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { usecontext } from '../context/productocontext';

function Addproduct(props) {
   const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
   const { productnew } = usecontext();
   const [imagen, setimagen] = useState([])

   const onSubmit = async (data) => {
      try {
         // Crea un nuevo objeto FormData
         const formData = new FormData();
        //  console.log('data',data.image)
         // Agrega los datos del formulario al objeto FormData
         Object.keys(data).map(key => {
              if(key === 'image'){

                setimagen(data.image)

                formData.append('image', imagen)
                
                console.log('valor de estado', imagen)
                console.log('datafile',data.image)
                // formData.append('image', data.image)
                console.log('image', data.image)
              }else{

                formData.append(key, data[key]);
              }
                 
              console.log('formdata', data)
          
            
         });
            

         // Envía el objeto FormData al backend

         const res = await productnew(formData);
         console.log('Respuesta del backend:', res);
      } catch (error) {
         console.error('Error al enviar formulario:', error);
      }
   };



   return (
      <div>
         <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} encType="multipart/form-data">
          
            Descripción <input type="text" {...register('descripcion')} />
            Precio <input type="text" {...register('priceproduct')} />
            Subir archivo <input type="file" name='image' {...register('image')} />
            <button type="submit">Guardar producto</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   );
}

export default Addproduct;


Cita en bloque
//mi backend es el siguiente tengo un archivo app que esta configurado mi proyecto, //aqui configure multer , nose si lo tenga mal configurado
Cita en bloque

import express from 'express'
import userRouter from './routes/userRouter.js'
import productoRouter from './routes/productoRouter.js'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import {join, dirname} from 'path'
import path from 'path';
import multer from 'multer'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

 const app = express()


 

 //configuracion de multer y para ver las imagenes en el navegador

 const storageconfi = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/public', 'uploads'),
   filename: (req, file, cb)=>{//esto es para renombrar  archivo con originalname
      cb(null, file.originalname)
   }
 })

 //Ruta del directorio actual y configuración de middleware estático

 const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);//console.log(__filename)
  
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);//console.log(__dirname)

 app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')));


// middlewares
 app.use(cors({
    origin:'http://localhost:5173',
    credentials: true
 }))
 
 app.use(morgan('dev'))
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(cookieParser());



// middleware de carga de archivo
app.use(multer({
  storage: storageconfi 
  //  dest: uploadDir
 }).single('image'))
  


 

 //rutas
 app.use("/api",userRouter)
 app.use("/api",productoRouter)

 export default app;


Cita en bloque
mi controladores de ruta son estos
Cita en bloque
Cita en bloque

//mis controladores de ruta son los siguientes


Cita en bloque

import {Router}  from "express";
import {  createproduct} from "../controllers/productocontroller.js";
import { validatetoken } from "../middelwares/validateToken.js";




const router = Router();
router.post("/createproduct",validatetoken,createproduct);//crearu un producto


Cita en bloque

este es el archivo donde requiero a req.file para luego manipularlo, aun guardo nada, pues si no tiene sentido seguir los siguientes pasos si no puedo obtener datos del frontend

Cita en bloque

import categori from "../models/categoriaModel.js"
import product from "../models/productoModel.js"
import image from "../models/imagenModel.js"
import {uploadimage} from "../config/reqfile.js"
import multer from "multer"
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { object } from "zod"





export const createproduct = async (req, res) => {



    try {
        
        // const { descripcion, priceproduct}= req.body
        const file = req.file
        
         console.log('el archivo es ',file)
        
        


        res.json('todo correcto')


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).json(["no existe una categoria"])
    }




}


Podrias usar el boton [edit] y sacar todas esas partes que dicen cita en bloque... que no se que quieren decir...

Revisa de que tipo es data.image, puede ser que estes recibiendo un array. Comparte lo que te muestra en consola.
